# import android packages cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My android application, built inside Eclipse, suddenly fails to build with dozens of errors.  The most obvious are errors indicating that all the android imports cannot be resolved.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
```

All of these are flagged as unresolvable.  I've tried removing and re-adding the JRE System Library.  I've tried cleaning and rebuilding.  I've tried the "Quick fix" option to "Fix Project Setup..." but that simply responds with a dialog box that say...

"**No proposals have been found to fix the unresolvable reference to 'android.app.Bundle'.  Click here to manually configure the build path of project 'Silent Mode Toggle."**

I'm new to Android development and this one has me completely stumped.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Rich

Comment: somehow your Android SDK got removed or corrupted. Check `Window->preferences->Android` and see if the SDK path listed at the top still correctly points to a valid SDK installation.

Comment: The SDK doesn't even need to get removed or corrupted, Eclipse may simply not be pointed at it in this instance.  That can easily happen if you make a new workspace, import a project, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton my mistake the SDK itself is not necessarily removed or corrupted, it could be the path to it that eclipse stores.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding System JRE: instead, you need to add Android library, which internally will include the JRE.  See here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/688/screenshot20120720at190.png/

Comment: @AleksG mention of system JRE makes me wonder if this was created as a generic Java project rather than as an Android project

Comment: @ChrisStratton Possibly, but I understood from the question that it did build before and now it doesn't.

Comment: This project was created as an Android project, not a Java project.  It was a sample program from a book and was built originally as an application, then it was converted to a widget.  That's when things went wrong.  The app was small, so I re-created the project and it now builds fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems that your `eclipse-workspace` (or at least your `Project`) is broken somehow.

Have you moved your `android-sdk/Project` recently? If it's not an Android Project anymore, try to look at `Preferences->Android` for a valid `android sdk-location`.

If this is correct, try to open a complete new Workspace, and import your sources with `File->import->Android Project` from existing Source.

If this still doesn't help, make a new android `Project` and copy the sources manually inside your `Project` from outside `Eclipse`. Re-open Eclipse after that, and make a `Project->clean`

Comment: Sometimes just restarting your elipse would get rid of this. Worked for me !

Answer (score 16):

What all the others said.

Specifically, I recommend you go to `Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries` and make sure you have exactly one copy of `android.jar` referenced.  (Sometimes you can get two if you're importing a project.)  And that its path is correct.

Sometimes you can get the system to resolve this for you by clicking a different target SDK in `Project > Properties > Android`, then restoring your original selection.

Answer (score 9):

right click on project->properties->android->select target name as "Android 4.4.2" --click ok

> since DocumentsContract is added in API level 19

Comment: tnx buddy, this is the answer for me.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem after accepting a Java update--scores of build errors and android import not recognized.  On checking the build path in Project=>Properties, I found that the check box for Android 4.3 had somehow gotten cleared. Checking it resolved all the import errors without my even having to restart the IDE or run a project clean.

Comment: I believe that this is the correct way to go (especially if you dont want to create a new workspace or project)

Answer (score 1):

try this in eclipse: `Window - Preferences - Android` - SDK Location and setup SDK path

Comment: I created a new project and this problem went away.  I suspect the suggestion of a corrupted reference to the SDK was correct.

Comment: @RichWooley you can mark the answer as accepted, to tell others that this question was solved!! This is how to accept answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

This `import android packages cannot be resolved` is also occurs when your using some library and that library is not in the same path where your application is there, or if you are importing the library and not coping library to the workspace

Answer (score 1):

May be you are using this checking :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
}
```

To resolve this you need to import  `android.provider.DocumentsContract` class.

> To resolve this issue you'll need to set the build SDK version to 19
> (4.4) or higher to have API level 19 symbols available while
> compiling.
>
> First, use the SDK Manager to download API 19 if you don't have it
> yet. Then, configure your project to use API 19:
>
> - In Android Studio: File -> Project Structure -> General Settings -> Project SDK.
> - In Eclipse ADT: Project Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target

I found the answer quoted above [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20375277/3073945), by [laalto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101361/laalto)

Answer (score 1):

```
RightClick on the Project > Properties > Android > Fix project properties
```

This solved it for me. easy.

Answer (score 0):

To import android packages, ADT plugin of eclipse is required, only after this you
can add it in the java build path.

Go to your eclipse market and download the Android AD extension.