# All imports error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Yesterday, my kid has turned off my PC by unplug it directly from the wall electricity source. When I launched Android Studio today, as you can see in the picture...

[image]

I tried:

- Checking the SDK location.
- Rebuild the project.
- Restart Android Studio.
- Sync project's gradle file.

Any Help?

Comment: Have you tried to sync your project's gradle file?

Comment: can you post any errors on gradle log, when you try to sync your project's gradle file?

Comment: @icaneatclouds picture added

Comment: There are some good suggestions [in this SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584539/import-android-packages-cannot-be-resolved)

Answer (score 15):

In android Studio open File--->Invalidate Caches/Restart and select Invalidate and Restart.hope that help

Answer (score 1):

It's a guess, but maybe it can't find your Android SDK for whatever reason.

Try checking the path (Assuming Android Studion 1.1.0):

File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location

Check that SDK location is linked to your Android SDK correctly

Comment: I did before and every thing is OK.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project? Build -> Clean Project.

Comment: Consider updating your question with a list of things you have tried; That will ensure you don't get a lot of redundant suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Please Change your SDK Location.and that's it