# No proposals have been found to fix the unresolvable reference to 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView'

Tags: android, adview

I dont know how it happend.Now in my code it says 'The import com.google.android.gms.ads cannot be resolved'.I have tried all the results in the answers here including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584539/import-android-packages-cannot-be-resolved) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164736/android-the-import-com-google-cannot-be-resolved)

I'm stuck with it.
It still exists. google play services is there. Im not sure about my attempts were in right path or not.So helpers pls describe it in step by step.thanks in advance.

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;

ERROR:
The import com.google.android.gms.ads cannot be resolved

Comment: have you attached  google lib.

Comment: Are you using eclipse or Android studio...?

Comment: Also please post your code..and where you are getting this error.

Comment: i'm new in android so please tell me how to check google lib.Also,it was a working project till yesterday.I didnt changed anything.i think it is because of when the power supply suddenly gone,the eclipse closed ubnormally.

Comment: @sandeep Eclipse.And error is in the import statements itself.

Comment: Its clear you did not import librarys. Please follow this steps in google developer website . https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eclipse

Comment: If you still face any error. please ask.happy to help.

Comment: im half way reached.I choose right click on my project->properties ->android .In that a library in green tick and another in red into mark symbol,which is missing.below the project title there is only a question mark.How can i add google-play-services_lib to that place?